# Get the device set up email accounts with phonegap Latest Versionandroid

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to get the device information in phonegap Android using below plugin
[Device Information Plugin-Phonegap](https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin.)

But I am getting below exception

> Uncaught module DeviceInformation not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:59

I didn't done any changes in cordova.js.this is automatically coming when I created the application.

If anyone konw the answer, Please help me.
Thanks in advance